# Why can't I see the +1 button on some apps in the Play Store app?

Tags: google-play-store

In the Play Store app, I find the `+1` button on some app pages, but not all app pages.  For example, *Smart Tools* and *Asphalt 7: Heat* are missing the button.  Why is this?

**Interesting:** This behavior is dynamic. Means, few minutes ago, I was unable to find `+1` button on Smart Tools app page. Now, its there. And, few minutes ago, `+1` button was on Camera Zoom FX app page. Now, its gone.

Some key information which might be useful:

- I am NOT talking about web interface. I am talking about app pages in Play Store.
- My device is Samsung Galaxy S with GB 2.3.5. Interestingly, my Nexus 7 (with JB 4.1) doesn't have this problem.
- My Play Store version is 3.9.16.
- My carrier is Reliance GSM in India.

I have taken screenshot of two of top paid apps' pages which doesn't have `+1` button:
[image: SwiftKey 3 app page of Play Store]
[image: Tasks app page of Play Store]

You can see in the screenshot that SwiftKey 3 & Tasks don't have `+1` button.

**The Dynamic Behavior:**
[image: Camera Zoom FX app page of Play Store]
You can see in the screenshot that Camera Zoom FX app page does have `+1` button. Few minute later its gone:
[image: Camera Zoom FX app page of Play Store]

**Update:**
Few minutes ago, SwiftKey 3 app page didn't have `+1` button, but now its there:
[image: SwiftKey 3 app page of Play Store]